# Magic Mouse Sticks in Full Clamshell

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, closed-clamshell

I have been using my MBP (13" mid-2009 running OSX 10.9.5) in clamshell mode with an external monitor connected via minidisplay port, Apple wireless keyboard, and magic mouse for a couple of months. Starting a few weeks ago the mouse would not recognize left clicks anymore and remain stuck on a random spot on the screen with a left click *when I close the MBP and try to work in clamshell mode*. It still tracks, so that when I move the mouse it highlights from where it got stuck. Also right clicks still work; but obviously they are no use without being able to left click. Also, the keyboard works without any issues.

This *problem disappears when I open the lid minimally* without waking the MBP monitor. This workaround was suggested [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mouse-lag-in-clamshell-mode.1154051/#post-13951031). Similar fixes that people have suggested such as [removing any plugged-in USB devices](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2445439?start=0&tstart=0) do not apply because there isn't anything plugged in besides the MDP and the magsafe connector.

Additionally, I believe that it's not a hardware issue because it worked previously, i.e. an external bluetooth dongle or wrapping aluminum foil around the MDP should not be required.

Any suggestions or fixes?

Thanks!

Comment: My macbook used to do this weird thing where it wouldnt play any noise even with the volume all the way up (and nothing would be plugged into the headphone jack), but when id plug my headphones in and take them out again, that would fix it. So maybe just plugging something into the usb slots and taking it out would do something. Sounds ridiculous i know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've plugged and unplugged a number of device since the problem first occured. So, unfortunately, that does not fix it for me.

Answer (score 1):

**News Flash edit**

[Found this discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mouse-lag-in-clamshell-mode.1154051/#post-13951031) which strongly suggests it is a hardware problem but not the mouse itself. One guy solved it by using a USB dongle.

My original answer remains below, un-edited.

**end News Flash edit**

---

Never had this problem w/ my magic mouse, nonetheless...

**Get back to a default** - disable any 3rd party enhancement software. Reset mouse system preferences to defaults.

[Magic Mouse iFixIt video search](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Magic_Mouse)

From there, **Here's an interesting video**: [Can I DYI fix a Broken Left-Click Resistance?](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/158993/Can+I+DYI+fix+a+broken+left-click+resistance). The tear down may not be something you want to do. I think I would try because the mouse seems pretty useless in its current state. iFixIt sells tools and parts for doing this kind of stuff.

P.S. I liked my magic mouse perfectly fine. In the PC world this thing is E.T. alien technology. Anyway, I like using the magic trackpad much more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @radarbob. I might have not made this clear enough but the MM hardware is fine. It works perfect with just the MBP, the MBP + external monitor, and "This problem disappears when I open the lid minimally without waking the MBP monitor." Also, I did not install any 3rd party enhancement software.

Comment: Ok. see my answer edit.

Comment: Yes, that is the discussion I referenced in my original post. However, I do not see how it can be the BT chip if it worked previously; unless it can deteriorate at a surprising rate. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.